# Virus upload scanning asp.net

Tags: asp.net, upload, virus

How do you prevent people uploading viruses to your asp.net windows website ? The only user content I'll be showing are images, sounds and video, can these contain viruses ?

Answer (score 2):

Certain clients/browser are exploitable using specially crafted images (ahem... IE). I'd say you are mostly fine, as long as *you* are writing the <object> tag and [sanitise your database inputs](http://xkcd.com/327/).

Also, if you would like to scan user content for viruses, a command-line scanner, such as that provided by NOD32, etc. can be used, but I think that's too processor-intensive for a website.